# Release occupied socket port occupied by coherence gracefully

Tags: java, sockets, oracle-coherence

Hi i have a particualar scenario in which when i start tomcat it also initializes some other services which actually binds on a particular port and starts listening on this port.

issue when ever i try to close tomcat the java process actually is not killed as this process keeps on listening that particular port. i actaully do not have any control over this bind nor i have the source code of the class  as  this is done by a third party jar.

so i just wanted to know is there a particular way by which i can abort listening to this port gracefully via java?

i have to use kill -9 every time to kill the process and release the port